# Plain TeX input Tikz package not found

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, packages, input, plain-tex

I ran

```
\input tikz.tex
\bye
```

and the Tikz package is not found

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021/MacPorts 2021.58693_2) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./a.tex
! I can't find file `tikz.tex'.
l.1 \input tikz.tex
```

Actually I am not able to input any TeX package in `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/plain`

```
$ ls /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/plain
amsfonts                fixpdfmag               kotex-plain             plstmary
antt                    font-change             kurier                  present
armenian                fontch                  lambda-lists            pwebmac
asapsym                 fp                      lh                      resumemac
base                    getoptk                 ly1                     rsfs
commutative-diagrams    gfnotation              makeindex               semaphor
config                  graphics-pln            metatex                 standalone
cweb                    gustlib                 mkpattern               timetable
cweb-old                hanoi                   newsletr                treetex
cyrplain                harvmac                 omega                   tugboat-plain
encxvlna                hyplain                 pgf                     varisize
enigma                  iwona                   pgfplots                velthuis
epsf-dvipdfmx           js-misc                 pitex                   vntex
esint-type1             knitting                placeins-plain          wasy
etex                    knuth-lib               plipsum                 zztex
figflow                 knuth-local             plnfss
```

How can I fix this?

Just out of curiosity: which paths does TeX search for when I `\input` a package through plain TeX?

Comment: `tikz.tex` is in `$TEXMFDIST/tex/plain/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.tex`.  The `pgf` tree is there, so I assume `tikz.tex` should be too...

Comment: if you go `tex plain.tex` what path does it show?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/plain/base/plain.tex
Preloading the plain format: codes, registers, parameters, fonts, more fonts,
macros, math definitions, output routines, hyphenation
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/hyphen/hyphen.tex
! Patterns can be loaded only by INITEX.`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik hmm `echo $TEXMFDIST` returns empty return .. so are you suggesting I should be `\input` the absolute path?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I did `\input /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/plain/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.tex

\bye` and then got the error `I can't find file pgf.tex.
l.17 \input pgf.tex`

Comment: @zmkm No, not the absolute path, kpse should do that for you.  You should be able to see the value of `$TEXMFDIST` with `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFDIST`.  But You show your TeX tree at `/usr/local/texlive`, but in your comment TeX seems to be looking at `/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive`... Something looks off

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks for pointing that out, I deleted the tex in `/opt/local/share` and now `pdftex` is pointing to `/usr/local/texlive/2021` and `\input tikz.tex` worked. But `\input amsfonts.tex` doesn't work, and amsfonts is the first package when I `ls /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/plain`

Comment: @zmkm I don't think there is an `amsfonts.tex`, only an `amsfonts.sty`...

Comment: as I suspected, you have two tex installations one under /opt (that you ar using) and one under /usr/local  (that you are looking at th file list for)

Comment: there is no `amsfonts.tex` file in texlive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two tex installations one rooted at `/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive` and another at `/usr/local/texlive/2021`  you presumably have your PATH set so the tex from the first tree is being used, and the file listings that you show are from the second tree.

The second question asked in comments about `\input amsfonts.tex` not finding a file is expected, that directory is called `amsfonts` but does not have a file `amsfonts.tex`:

```
$ ls /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/plain/amsfonts/
amssym.def  amssym.tex  cyracc.def
```